# jade version of zipcodeapi example

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to create a jade version to do autofill city state from 
https://www.zipcodeapi.com/Examples

```
script(type='text/javascript').
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
    // IMPORTANT: Fill in your client key
    console.log("thing")
    var clientKey = "js-9qZHzu2Flc59Eq5rx10JdKERovBlJp3TQ3ApyC4TOa3tA8U7aVRnFwf41RpLgtE7";
    var cache = {};
    var container = $("#example1");
    var errorDiv = container.find("div.text-error");
    /** Handle successful response */
    function handleResp(data)
    {
        // Check for error
        if (data.error_msg)
            errorDiv.text(data.error_msg);
        else if ("city" in data)
        {
            // Set city and state
            container.find("input[name='city']").val(data.city);
            console.log(data.city);
            container.find("input[name='state']").val(data.state);
        }
    }
    // Set up event handlers
    container.find("input[name='zipcode']").on("keyup change", function() {
        // Get zip code
        var zipcode = $(this).val().substring(0, 5);
        if (zipcode.length == 5 && /^[0-9]+$/.test(zipcode))
        {
            // Clear error
            errorDiv.empty();
            // Check cache
            if (zipcode in cache)
            {
                handleResp(cache[zipcode]);
            }
            else
            {
            //Build url
            var url = "https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/"+clientKey+"/info.json/" + zipcode + "/radians";
                // Make AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    "url": url,
                    "dataType": "json"
                }).done(function(data) {
                    handleResp(data);
                    // Store in cache
                    cache[zipcode] = data;
                }).fail(function(data) {
                    if (data.responseText && (json = $.parseJSON(data.responseText)))
                    {
                        // Store in cache
                        cache[zipcode] = json;
                        // Check for error
                        if (json.error_msg)
                            errorDiv.text(json.error_msg);
                    }
                    else
                        errorDiv.text('Request failed.');
                });
            }
        }
    }).trigger("change");
});
//]]>
div#example1
label Zip:
input(type='text', name='zipcode', value='')
label City:
input(type='text', name='city', value='')
label State:
input(type='text', name='state', value='')
```

I am getting the following error and not sure why this is erroring out:

```
$ is not defined
```

Any ideas?  This is a conversion from the original javascript so I am not sure what I am doing wrong in the conversion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Always listen to your error messages; they're usually right. `$` isn't defined. Have you included jQuery (just guessing) in a higher-level template, of which this is a subtemplate? If not, `$ is undefined` is a valid message from the javascript interpreter.